# TypeError (discord.js v14) - SlashCommandbuilder is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Terminal error:

```
    \commands\ping.js:4
    data: new SlashCommandbuilder()
          ^

TypeError: SlashCommandbuilder is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\MichelDev\Pessoais JM\Relphi (BOT)\commands\ping.js:4:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\MichelDev\Pessoais JM\Relphi (BOT)\index.js:20:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
```

Codding (commands/ping.js)

```
const { SlashCommandbuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders"); 
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandbuilder()
        .setName("ping")
        .setDescription("Pong."),
    async execute(interaction)
    {
        interaction.reply("Pong!"); 
    }
}
```

Codding (commands/index.js)

```
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require("fs");
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v10");
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Collection } = require("discord.js");
//const config = ("./config.js");
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
    ]
});

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));
const commands = [];
client.commands = new Collection();

for (const file of commandFiles)
{
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

client.once("ready", () => 
{
    console.log("(Discord.js v14) Ralphi online!");

    const CLIENT_ID = client.user.id;
    const rest = new REST
    ({
        version: "10"
    }).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

    (async () =>  
    {
        try {
            if(process.env.ENV === "production")
            {
                await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID), 
                {
                    body: commands
                });
                console.log("Comandos registrados com sucesso (global).");
            }
            else 
            {
                await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, process.env.GUILD_ID), 
                {
                    body: commands
                });
                console.log("Comandos registrados com sucesso (local).");               
            }
        }
        catch(err)
        {
                if(err) console.error(err);
        }
    })();
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I'm creating a bot for the first time on discord.js (v14) and using it as a way of learning, but when I started to assemble these "SlashCommandBUilder", it wasn't. But before that there was an error in the main code (index.js) that is needed for this "CommandBuilder". I don't know what else to do, so I ask you to help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: All questions and answers on the main Stack Overflow site are [required to be in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/205114). For help in Portuguese  try [pt.so], but be sure to follow their [content guidelines](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to Ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ensure an on-topic question.

Comment: As of DiscordJS v14, builders are now included in the core library. Require the builder from `'discord.js'`

Comment: As much as I put the ('const { SlashCommandbuilder } = require("discord.js'); it doesn't work. The code keeps giving the same error.

Comment: The correct casing is `SlashCommandBuilder` with a capital B

Comment: Solved, thanks everyone for the help. In fact the error was what you warned me about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the letter B in the builder part (SlashCommandbuilder) should be uppercase. Like SlashCommandBuilder

Comment: Solved, thanks everyone for the help. In fact the error was what you warned me about.