# Javascript: (Discord.js) - TypeError: SlashCommandBuilder is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor, discord, discord.js

On the line with asterisks (*) executing the code returns an error of `TypeError: SlashCommandBuilder is not a constructor`

```
//party command
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    *data: new SlashCommandBuilder()*
        .setName('party')
        .setDescription('Creates a party which others can join based on roles')
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName('gamemode')
            .setDescription('The name of the gamemode')
                .setRequired(true)
                .addChoices(
                    { name: 'Hardcore', value: 'hc' },
                    { name: 'Fallen', value: 'fn' },
                { name: 'Molten', value: 'mn' },
                        { name: 'Normal', value: 'nm' },
                        { name: 'Badlands II', value: 'bl' },
                        { name: 'Polluted Wastelands II', value: 'pw' },
                        { name: 'Pizza Party', value: 'pp' },
                        { name: 'Other', value: 'ot' },
                )),
        async execute(interaction) {
            await interaction.reply('You ran /party');
        },
};
```

I am following a [guide](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#individual-command-files) In the guide, scroll down to `commands/ping.js`. It appears to use `SlashCommandBuilder` as a constructor. I have expanded on it since and I'm confused about this. Thank you for your help.

Node.js v18.12.1

npm list
discord.js@12.5.3
dotenv@16.0.3

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73749199/typeerror-discord-js-v14-slashcommandbuilder-is-not-a-constructor) which was made for the same reason, however the error was thrown due to a capitalization error of `SlashCommandBuilder`

Comment: In your current `discord.js` version, the `SlashCommandBuilder` didn't yet exist. It only came in `discord.js` v13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Discord.JS version you are using (v12) is simply outdated therefore it does not support recent features like slash commands, I recommend checking out [this guide to learn the basic differences of V14.](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#before-you-start)

If you are still struggling I recommend finding more resources online on the latest version.